# FLAC files getting corrupted on microSD card

Tags: sd-card, samsung-galaxy-s-5, lineageos, adoptable-storage, poweramp

Whenever I put a FLAC album on my phone, after a few days some of the tracks get corrupted. They show errors when I bring them onto my PC and use the command line function `flac -t *.flac`. While most tracks result in an `ok`, some result in errors such as `FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_ERROR_STATUS_LOST_SYNC` or `FLAC__STREAM_DECODER_ERROR_STATUS_FRAME_CRC_MISMATCH`. I am using LineageOS 15.1 (July 23 build) on my SM-G900P with a genuine SanDisk 128GB Extreme PLUS microSD card formatted as adopted/internal storage. I read somewhere about a LOST.DIR folder being used as a recycling bin for corrupted files or something like that, but I don't seem to have that folder.

Is this an issue with Samsung, Android, LineageOS, Poweramp (my music player), or my SD card? I really hope it's not an SD card issue because I don't feel like spending so much time formatting/moving a ton of data around.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you compared the original file(s) with a corrupted one to see what the difference is? On Windows you can use the integrated comand-line tool ' fc.exe -b file1 file2`.

Comment: I suggest performing extensive file-system checks of the sd card from a PC. `fsck` and `smartctl` are your friends if you're on linux. Look for filesystem check apps and SMART readers on windows.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly an SD card issue, especially since initially the files are fine and not corrupt, and get that way over time. Your device and it's applications will only read the data from the SD card, not change it or write to it anyway. There is a very slim chance that the card reader in your phone is defective, but I think a safe bet would be the card itself is failing.

This is the most definitive answer I can offer with the information given.

I am not normally one to recommend a specific brand here, but my personal experience with SanDisk has been very disappointing in terms of reliability in multiple product lines they carry. I would recommend moving away from SanDisk and trying perhaps a Samsung EVO+ series card.

Comment: It seems like I had this issue with my previous Extreme PLUS 32GB card, so you could be right.

Comment: Actually, my files could've been corrupted as soon as I copied them to my phone, but I just didn't know it.

Comment: @Pete The test would be to transfer them to internal storage, if they are corrupt try copying them to Google Drive (or your favorite online storage) and then to the device.

Comment: I meant my files could've been corrupted as soon as I copied them to my phone, but I just didn't know it until I played the files. I just copied an entire FLAC album to my SD card using the USB connection from my phone to my Win10 laptop. I then copied the entire album back and tested it and a couple of songs were messed up. Re-copying only the affected songs to the phone's SD card seemed to fix the issue, but I didn't copy the *entire* album back for testing, so I'm not sure if other files weren't affected by the re-copying. This could be an issue with Win10 copying stuff to Android phones.

Comment: Just copied the entire album in question from my phone to my laptop and tested it. No errors. I'm still kind of paranoid that the files will eventually somehow become corrupt over time, but it looks like my SD card is fine and this is just a USB file transfer issue that that easily (but tediously) be worked around.